# Transformation does not work correctly

Tags: wpf, transformation, rotatetransform, transformgroup

Here is my code which rotates my object. I have to rotate two same type of objects.

> initialization:

```
private TransformGroup trGrp;
        private RotateTransform trRot;
        private TransformGroup trGrp1;
        private RotateTransform trRot1;
        static private double angle;
        SerialPort port;
        value v;
        string result;
        public int zeroValue;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            angle = 0;
            zeroValue = 327;
            trGrp = new TransformGroup();
            trRot = new RotateTransform(angle) { CenterX = rectangle1.Width / 2, CenterY = rectangle1.Height };
            trGrp1 = new TransformGroup();
            trRot1 = new RotateTransform(angle) { CenterX = rectangle1.Width / 2, CenterY = rectangle1.Height };
           // trGrp.Children.Add(trRot);
            //trGrp1.Children.Add(trRot1);
            v = new value();
            port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            port.Open();
        }
```

> Code For serial port received data:

```
void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!port.IsOpen)
            { 
                port.Open(); 
            }

            try
            {
                result = port.ReadLine();
                result = result.Replace("\r", "");
            }

            catch (Exception e1)
            { MessageBox.Show(e1.Message); }
            int[] temp = new int[4];
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(
          delegate()
          {


              try
              {

                      temp[0] = int.Parse(result[1].ToString() + result[2].ToString() + result[3].ToString() + result[4].ToString());

                      if (temp[0] == zeroValue)
                      {

                          trRot.Angle = 0;
                          trGrp.Children.Add(trRot);
                          rectangle1.RenderTransform = trGrp;
                          trGrp.Children.RemoveAt(0);//because Add function adds a new trGrp so its size increases and we do not need old trGrp so we remove them.
                          label3.Content = trRot.Angle.ToString();

                      }

                      else if (temp[0] > zeroValue)
                      {

                          int totalValues = temp[0] - zeroValue;
                          if (totalValues == 1) 
                          {
                              totalValues = 0;
                          }
                          textBox3.Text = temp[0].ToString();
                          angle = totalValues * Properties.Settings.Default.angle;

                          if (angle<31)
                          {
                              trRot.Angle = angle / 2;
                              trGrp.Children.Add(trRot);
                              rectangle1.RenderTransform = trGrp;
                              //trGrp.Children.RemoveAt(1);//because Add function adds a new trGrp so its size increases and we do not need old trGrp so we remove them.
                              trGrp.Children.Remove(trRot);
                              label3.Content = angle.ToString();
                          }




                      }
                      else if (temp[0] < zeroValue)
                      {

                          int totalValues = zeroValue - temp[0];
                          if (totalValues==1)
                          {
                              totalValues = 0;
                          }
                          textBox3.Text = temp[0].ToString();
                          angle = -totalValues * Properties.Settings.Default.angle;

                          if (angle> -21)
                          {
                              trRot.Angle = angle / 2;
                          trGrp.Children.Add(trRot);
                          rectangle1.RenderTransform = trGrp;
                          trGrp.Children.Remove(trRot);//because Add function adds a new trGrp so its size increases and we do not need old trGrp so we remove them.
                          label3.Content = angle.ToString();
                          }




                      }

              }
              catch (Exception)
              { }
          }
      ));
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(
          delegate()
          {

              try
              {
                  temp[1] = int.Parse(result[6].ToString() + result[7].ToString() + result[8].ToString() + result[9].ToString());
                  if (temp[1] == zeroValue)
                  {

                      trRot1.Angle = 0;
                      trGrp.Children.Add(trRot1);
                      rectangle2.RenderTransform = trGrp1;
                      trGrp1.Children.RemoveAt(1);//because Add function adds a new trGrp so its size increases and we do not need old trGrp so we remove them.
                      // textBox3.Text = trRot.Angle.ToString();
                      label4.Content = angle.ToString();

                  }

                  else if (temp[1] > zeroValue)
                  {

                      int totalValues = temp[1] - zeroValue;
                      if (totalValues == 1)
                      {
                          totalValues = 0;
                      }
                      angle = totalValues * Properties.Settings.Default.angle;
                      angle = Math.Round(angle, 0);
                      if (angle < 21)
                      {
                          trRot1.Angle = angle / 2;
                          trGrp1.Children.Add(trRot1);
                          rectangle2.RenderTransform = trGrp1;
                          trGrp1.Children.RemoveAt(0);//because Add function adds a new trGrp so its size increases and we do not need old trGrp so we remove them.
                          label4.Content = angle.ToString();
                      }
                  }
                  else if (temp[1] < zeroValue)
                  {

                      int totalValues = zeroValue - temp[1];
                      if (totalValues == 1)
                      {
                          totalValues = 0;
                      }
                      angle = -totalValues * Properties.Settings.Default.angle;

                      if (angle > -21)
                      {
                          trRot1.Angle = angle / 2;
                          trGrp1.Children.Add(trRot1);
                          rectangle2.RenderTransform = trGrp1;
                          trGrp1.Children.RemoveAt(0);//because Add function adds a new trGrp so its size increases and we do not need old trGrp so we remove them.
                          label4.Content = angle.ToString();
                      }


                  }
              }
              catch (Exception)
              {


              }
          }));


        }
```

I have used here two Dispatcher.BeginInvok' functions because i want to rotate both objects simultaneously. But the issue is that when i use only one object to rotate then no issue come. But when i include second one the first objects does not rotate correctly according to the angle i have mentioned in my program. What i understand that it is a problem that everytime event is fired transformGroup adds a new rotateTransform. So i tried to remove the added TrRot after addition. But this also does not work for me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just add the animations in XAML? Also, using `Dispatcher.Invoke` does *not* mean that your code will run in parallel... it just adds your requests onto the main UI thread queue, just the same as if you add two animations in XAML.

Comment: Would it be a different result? I had to write Event handler for Serial Port data received thats why i wrote it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple `Trigger` to start your animations in XAML... let's say you add a `bool` property named `IsReady`. You could then trigger your animations to start when you set this to `true` and to stop when you set it to `false`. Add this `Style` to whichever objects contain the `RotateTransform` object that needs to be animated:

```
<Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReady}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.
(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="359" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```